# How to show new lines on enter in mail from PHP contact form?

Tags: php, email

The form is working, but the textarea input has no new lines. 
The whole message is showed on a single line.

FYI, my textarea has no CSS. And I have changed the email adress for privacy purposes.

Thanks in advance,
Sam

```
<?php

$emailAddress = $_POST["email"];
$firstName = $_POST["firstName"];
$lastName = $_POST["lastName"];
$textMessage = $_POST["message"];
$to = "contact@website.com";
/*standard headers for HTML mail*/
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8\r\n";
/*Add. headers*/
$headers .= 'From: ' . $emailAddress . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-to: ' . $emailAddress . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'First name: ' . $firstName . "<br>";
$headers .= 'Last name: ' . $lastName . "<br><br>";
$headers .= 'Message:'."<br><br>";

$status = mail($to, "New client inquiry", $textMessage, $headers);

if($status)
{
    echo "<p>Your mail has been send succesfully!</p>";
}
else
{
    echo "<p>Your mail has not been delivered, please try again</p>";
} 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the content type of mail as `text/html`, so it expects the content to be valid HTML.

As you should know, newlines have no effect on html rendering. BR or P tags should be used.

Either transform your message in proper HTML (replacing newlines with BR) or change the content type to `text/plain`.

By the way CSS has nothing to do here (won't alter the content of value sent during request).